# How to fix problem with nvd3 events on firefox?

Tags: angular, d3.js, nvd3.js

I need to get click position from this event:

```
stacked: {
  dispatch: {
    elementClick: () => alert('stacked.dispatch'),
  },
},
```

While I have this option: `useInteractiveGuideline: false`.

The main problem is that this option doesn't work in Firefox.

Here's a [LINK](https://codepen.io/andy-ivanyuk/pen/XvmqoR?editors=1010). Try it in Chrome and Firefox please.
Note that there should be an alert message when you click on chart.

Maybe there is any tip to prevent toggling separate stacked area with `useInteractiveGuideline: true` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's some bug with [angular-nvd3](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3) directive. Created the stackedAreaChart using pure nvd3 and events work fine in both Chrome and Firefox.

```
  var chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
                .x(function(d) { return d.x })
                .y(function(d) { return d.y })
                .clipEdge(true)
                .showLegend(false)
                .showControls(false)
                .useInteractiveGuideline(false)
                ;


  chart.stacked.dispatch.on('elementClick', function(e) {
    alert('element click');
  });

  chart.stacked.dispatch.on('areaClick', function(e) {
    alert('area click');
  });
```

Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ovvn/kgm5bxaz/2/).